# finding lim x-> 0 (-5+x)^2-25/x

Tags: limits

The solution is -10 but I always come out with x on the bottom resulting in 0. I must be doing something wrong when I take (-5+x)^2-25 and simplify it to x^2.

Comment: Multiply out (or factor) the top, and then cancel the x on the bottom with a factor of x on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to confirm, is the question this?

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(x-5)^2-25}{x}$$

if so then you can expand it to

$$\frac{x^2 -10x+25-25}{x}$$

$$=\frac{x^2 -10x}{x}$$

$$={x -10}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}(x-10)=0-10=-10$$

Answer (score 0):

$(x^2-10x+25-25)/x$ 
Expansion of $(-5+x)^2$

The expression reduces to
$x-10$

So when x ->0, answer is -10

You might have expanded incorrectly